# Spark YARN on EMR - JavaSparkContext - IllegalStateException: Library directory does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I have Java Spark job that works on manually deployed Spark 1.6.0 in standalone mode on an EC2.

I am spark-submitting this job to a EMR 5.3.0 cluster on the master using YARN but it fails.

Spark-submit line is,

```
spark-submit --class <startclass> --master yarn --queue default --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://`hostname -f`:8020/tmp/ourSparkLogs --driver-memory 4G  --executor-memory 4G --executor-cores 2 hdfs://`hostname -f`:8020/data/x.jar yarn-client
```

The "yarn-client" is the first argument to the x.jar application and is fed to the SparkContext as setMaster,

```
conf.setMaster(args[0]);
```

When I submit it, it starts out running fine, until I initialize the JavaSparkContext from a SparkConf,

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

... and then Spark crashes.

In the YARN log, I can see the following,

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1487325147456_0051

...
17/02/17 16:27:13 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
17/02/17 16:27:13 INFO Client: Deleted staging directory hdfs://ip-172-31-8-237.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/ec2-user/.sparkStaging/application_1487325147456_0052
17/02/17 16:27:13 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory '/mnt/yarn/usercache/ec2-user/appcache/application_1487325147456_0051/container_1487325147456_0051_01_000001/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars' does not exist; make sure Spark is built.
...
```

Noting the WARN of spark.yarn.jars flag missing, I found a spark yarn JAR file in

```
/usr/lib/spark/jars/
```

... and uploaded it to HDFS per Cloudera's guide on how to run YARN applications on Spark and tried to add that conf, so this became my spark-submit line,

```
spark-submit --class <startclass> --master yarn --queue default --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://`hostname -f`:8020/tmp/ourSparkLogs --conf spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://`hostname -f`:8020/sparkyarnlibs/spark-yarn_2.11-2.1.0.jar --driver-memory 4G  --executor-memory 4G --executor-cores 2 hdfs://`hostname -f`:8020/data/x.jar yarn-client
```

But that did not work and gave this:

```
Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster
```

I am really puzzled as to what that Library error is caused by and how to proceed onwards from here.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified "--deploy-mode cluster" and yet are calling conf.setMaster("yarn-client") from the code. Using a master URL of "yarn-client" means "use YARN as the master, and use client mode (not cluster mode)", so I wouldn't be surprised if this is somehow confusing Spark because on one hand you're telling it to use cluster mode and on the other you're telling it to use client mode.

By the way, using a master URL like "yarn-client" or "yarn-cluster" is actually deprecated because the "-client" or "-cluster" part is not really part of the Master but rather is the deploy mode. That is, "--master yarn-client" is really more of a shortcut/alias for "--master yarn --deploy-mode client", and similarly "--master yarn-cluster" just means "--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster".

My recommendation would be to not call conf.setMaster() from your code, since the master is already set to "yarn" automatically in /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf. For this reason, you also don't need to pass "--master yarn" to spark-submit.

Lastly, it sounds like you need to decide whether you really want to use client deploy mode or cluster deploy mode. With client deploy mode, the driver runs on the master instance, and with cluster deploy mode, the driver runs in a YARN container on one of the core/task instances. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html for more information.

If you want to use client deploy mode, you don't need to pass anything extra because it's already the default. If you want to use cluster deploy mode, pass "--deploy-mode cluster".